# Codeigniter: If I get no query results then output nothing in view-file

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

In my model I return $query->row();

Then my view file echos that. But if I don't get any results from the database then I get an error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

If I don't get any result I just want it to echo nothing.

I can't find a good solution. 
I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check for sanity of your result, and never pass objects to the view.  Arrays and variables are ok.

```
// some query before this.
$result = $query->row();

// predefine variables in data.
$data['var1'] = "";
$data['var2'] = "";
$data['var3'] = "";

if($result !== false)
{
  $data['var1'] = $result->var1;
  $data['var2'] = $result->var2;
  $data['var3'] = $result->var3;
}

$this->load->view('myview', $data);
```

Comment: Check sanity. thanks.
but why shouldn't I pass objects to the view?

Comment: Imagine you will that you are not the only person using this code.  That a web designer with HTML/CSS skills may do editing of the view.  He/she doesn't understand php  It's easier for them to read variables than it is for them to understand objects.  It's best to keep it simple in the view.  arrays, and variables, with human readable names.